# Siamese Convolution Neural Network

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am trying to do human re-identification by using siamese convolution neural network in matlab. I am doing pre-training by using CUHK dataset, then fine tune by using training set in ViPeR dataset.

I plot the Cumulative Matching Characteristic (CMC) Curves result.

Result on testing set is increasing but not much, then decreasing and maintain after that, but for training set, it is keep increasing. Means that the training process is keep fitting the training set but not for testing.  It seems like my case is happening over-fitting, but when i apply some method like dropout to avoid over-fitting problem, the CMC results is same. 
The network model runs with this parameters learning rate= 0.001, mini batch size = 128, epoch = 300;

any ideas to improve the testing set CMC result?